# Expand Panel Only on Icon Click - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm working in an Angular 11 project with Material.

I'm using some expanding panels. I'm going to have a button in the header of an expanding panel. Because of this, I want the row to expand/collapse only when the arrow icon (on the right) is clicked. Right now the panel will expand/collapse if any part of the header is clicked.

I found this posting: [Angular Material Expansion panel, expand only on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113692/angular-material-expansion-panel-expand-only-on-button-click)
However that person's solution is to have their own button with an arrow icon rather than use the arrow icon that material panels already have. I would much rather use the icon that material provides in the panel than create my own button.

Is there some way for me to signal to material that I only want to expand when the toggle icon is selected? A property or something? I would think that many people would want to have type of functionality...
If not, is there a way for me to force this behavior? I don't want to create my own toggle button, I'd want to use the toggle in the panel.

I made this demo, showing my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-collapse-on-icon-click-only?file=src/app/expansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [stopPropation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on my-panel div element. It will prevent expansion panel open when you click on anypart of the header.

```
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
      <!-- #enddocregion multi -->
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div class="my-panel"  (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
            <h3>Panel Header</h3>
     <button mat-stroked-button (click)="myButton()">my button</button>
          </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    
        <div>My panel content!</div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/66655993expand-panel-only-on-icon-click-angular-material?file=src/app/expansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that example link is correct. It doesn't involve expanding panels.

Comment: sorry about wrong link i have update the example link

Comment: Wow! That's great, and it doesn't involve writing anymore functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Updated stackblitz link, open and look into and let me know if any I have used your existing code.

[example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-collapse-on-icon-click-only-wbarjv?file=src/app/expansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html)

Comment: This works great! Thank you! For others, this is what was added: 
Add an id tag to mat-expansion-panel, like #matExpansionPanel1
Add a click event to the mat-expansion-panel-header, like (click)="expandPanel(matExpansionPanel1, $event)"
Now you need to go make that expandPanel function in your class.
Please check out the example for more details on the func, but basically, it stops propagation, then determines if you're clicking the icon to decide if it should keep closed.